# App in emulator is not updating with the project and showing a different layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-emulator

First of all, I am a totally newbie in android studio IDE. When I am trying to show my project's results in the emulator, emulator shows me a different result than I created in project. For example layout is totaly different. I haven't play with any code or add a new java code yet. I was only started to learn about layouts and this problem came up. Also after I opened the emulator, any change I am making in project is being followed by the emulator. So, can you please help me about solving this problem ? I will add some screenshots:

[Here is the screenshot of my project for showing you How the project and emuator shows different screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ6fY.png)

[And here, when I add a progress bar on my project, emulator is not updating itself with this and still show the same screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amzeZ.png)

Comment: Clean the project... There is a menu option to do so in android studio

Comment: @deHaar I tried directly opening a different project and same problem was continuing.

Comment: What does a real device show? You can plug one in and use it like the emulator...

Comment: I tried and same like in emulator.

Comment: Well, please provide Java and xml code...

Comment: Guys I have just resolved the problem of not matching view. Now my only problem is about when I update something in my project, emulator is not reacting and stay same as view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used Constraint layout so you must have to give one horizontal and one vertical constraint to your views otherwise it will go to (0,0) place.

Comment: I just changed Constraint layout with relative layout and the problem in the first photo has gone. But still second problem continues. For see the changes which I made in the project, must close and open emulator again.

Comment: so after restarting the emulator does the progress bar show?

Comment: Yes everything I am adding or changing position is being shown in emulator when I open first time. But when emulator is open and I continue to add or change something in my project, emulator screen stays same and not changes. After any change I made,  I must open and close emulator for see the results.

Comment: Do you re-run the code when the emulator is open to check the view changes?

Comment: When I did re-run program, changes applied on emulator screen. But as I see in some tutorials, some of guys was not everytime re-running the project after every change, emulator was just simply updating itself without ask.

Comment: Any tutorial link which you see? Because as per my knowledge the android emulator doesn't updates automatically, we have to run the app to check it.

Comment: Maybe they was simply using the shortcut key of Apply Changes feature. When you click the " Apply Changes " button which is located right of the "Run" button, emulator is updating in a seconds.

Comment: Possible. So you get the solution?If yes kindly select the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't have set absolute positions in the xml file. If you go to see the xml this will have red lines under the word "TextView" and any other objects.

Fix it by drag the dots on the shape of the TextView to the edge of the layout of the screen.

Hope it helps.